# unicode of char misused for int

Tags: c++, c, unicode, unions

I'm writing a program that reads student grade whether it was a `char` or an `int` and store it in a `union`, then it prints the students whose grades are `A` or >90.

But when I try to do that I get an unexpected output because the program doesn't know which one (the char or the int) I want to compare.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union StuGrade {
    char charGrade;
    int intGrade;
};

struct Student {
    int ID;
    int typeOfGrade;
    union StuGrade grade;
};

int main () {
    const int size = 5; 
    struct Student *sList[size]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sList[i] = (struct Student *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Student));
        if (!sList[i]) {
            puts("Error allocating memory");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("Enter ID: "); 
        scanf("%d", &(sList[i]->ID)); 
        printf("0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: "); 
        scanf("%d", &(sList[i]->typeOfGrade));

        if (sList[i]->typeOfGrade) { 
            printf("Enter an int grade: ");
            scanf("%d", &(sList[i]->grade.intGrade)); 
        } else { 
            printf("Enter a char grade: ");
            scanf(" %c", &(sList[i]->grade.charGrade)); 
        }
    } //end for loop

    printf("\n***Student(s) who take grade 'A' is/are***\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (sList[i]->grade.charGrade == 'A') 
            printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %c \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.charGrade);
        else if (sList[i]->grade.intGrade >= 90) 
            printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %d \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.intGrade);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        free(sList[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Enter ID: 1
0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: 0
Enter a char grade: A
Enter ID: 2
0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: 0
Enter a char grade: b
Enter ID: 3
0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: 1
Enter an int grade: 99
Enter ID: 4
0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: 1
Enter an int grade: 84
Enter ID: 5
0 for char grade or 1 for int grade: 1
Enter an int grade: 65

***Student(s) who take grade 'A' is/are***
ID: 1 
Grade: A 
ID: 2 
Grade: 98 
ID: 3 
Grade: 99 
ID: 5 
Grade: A
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Could you post that?

Comment: Be careful when using both the C and C++ language tags, as they are very different languages. Especially when it comes to unions there is a semantic difference between the languages. So please edit your question to only include the language tag of the language you're really programming in.

Comment: As for your problem, you have saved the `typeOfGrade` in the structure itself, so why don't you use that when printing the grade?

Comment: @Chipster I think the expected result is that output is same as input. So student 1 would have "A", student 3 would have "99" and others are not shown.

Comment: Well, for one thing, 65 = 'A' in ASCII. That's why it is showing up. You probably want to take into account the type of grade. That will for sure fix that one.

Comment: Also, 'b' = 98 in ASCII, which is why it is also showing up. You only check for 'A' i. e. 65. If it is not 65, you assume it's an int. Again, to fix, take into account the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the type of grade in the comparison:

```
  if (sList[i]->typeOfGrade == 0 && sList[i]->grade.charGrade == 'A') 
     printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %c \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.charGrade);
  else if (sList[i]->typeOfGrade == 1 && sList[i]->grade.intGrade >= 90) 
     printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %d \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.intGrade);
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** My original answer used the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), but someone pointed out I should be using the [UTF-8 Table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec) instead. However, both are really similar for the purposes described here. However, technically compilers will often use UTF-8 instead of ASCII, so I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Ville-Valtteri has a perfectly good answer, but I would like to explain what's going on too.

So, please review the  [UTF-8 Table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec).

As hopefully you should know, every character on any computer gets translated into a number. This is determined by the aforementioned table.

In C and C++, these are sort of treated equally in the sense that if I assign a number to an char:

```
char c = 65;
```

It will treat it as the letter `'A'`.

Conversely, if I assign the letter `'A'` to an int:

```
int i = int('A');
```

You end up with the number `65`.

Okay, so now with your code. Let's look at your first test:

```
if (sList[i]->grade.charGrade == 'A')
```

You test to see if the value is == to `'A'`. Note you do not check for type, so 65 is perfectly acceptable for this test, **even if you added it as an int** because you are not testing for that. You are testing *ONLY* for `'A'` or its equivalent `65`.

Now, your second test:

```
else if (sList[i]->grade.intGrade >= 90)
```

So, if it's not a char grade 'A', it must be an int grade right? Wrong, because didn't test for if it's a char grade, only that it isn't char grade 'A'. Anything not that, and you get to this test.

That means the letter `'b'` would get to this test, which has a value of `98` (see the [UTF-8 table](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec) again). Since C and C++ treat numbers and letters as sort of the same (not technically, but close), it tests this as a int grade 98, even though it's intended to be a char grade. That means it passes you >= 90 check.

Which brings us to [Ville-Valtteri's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059056/10957435), which is to account for the type of grade in your check.

> ```
>  if (sList[i]->typeOfGrade == 0 && sList[i]->grade.charGrade == 'A') 
>     printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %c \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.charGrade);
>  else if (sList[i]->typeOfGrade == 1 && sList[i]->grade.intGrade >= 90) 
>     printf("ID: %d \nGrade: %d \n", sList[i]->ID, sList[i]->grade.intGrade);
> ```

Comment: "This is determined by the aforementioned table.": Not that table very often. In the case of literals like 'A', it would the table for the character encoding that the compiler is told to emit (`/execution-charset` or `-fexec-charset`). In the case of user input, a few things should be lined up: console's character encoding and program's current `locale`. In many cases, this century, all of these are UTF-8 (and unfortunately, in many cases, not). ASCII can be used as "least-common-denominator" reference but that is seldom what's actually in use. You already knew that  isn't ASCII, right?

Comment: Smiley faces? Yeah I knew those aren't ASCII. So what you're saying is that it uses the default/specified table. This used to be ASCII but now is ITF-8?

Comment: I can't think of a compiler were ASCII is/was the default. To be sure, ASCII is compatible with many other character encodings.  But, in practice, there is only one being used; the existence of similar ones is irrelevant.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Good point. I will change it when I get a chance. Is A and b still 65 and 98 in UTF-8?

Comment: @TomBlodget And edited. Feel free to proofread more if you like :)